# Mounting Azure File Storage to Azure Virtual Destop Session Host using Terraform and PowerShell Script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure, windows-virtual-desktop

I want to automatically mount an Azure File Share to Azure Virtual Desktop using Terraform and PowerShell Script at the provisioning time. Currently, I am using the CustomExtention PowerShell Script to mount the Azure File Share. However, I cannot achieve the goal, the UNC Path of the Azure File Share is not mounted automatically. I must access the Session Host and mount it by cmd or PowerShell. Below is my code.

Terraform Code:

```
locals {
  registration_token = azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool_registration_info.registrationinfo.token
  shutdown_command     = "shutdown -r -t 10"
  exit_code_hack       = "exit 0"
  commandtorun         = "New-Item -Path HKLM:/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/RDInfraAgent/AADJPrivate"
  powershell_command   = "${local.commandtorun}; ${local.shutdown_command}; ${local.exit_code_hack}"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg-avd" {
    name = var.resource_group_name
    location = var.location 
}

# Create AVD workspace
resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_workspace" "workspace" {
  name                = "AVD-${var.prefix}-Workspace"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.location
  friendly_name       = "AVD ${var.prefix} Workspace"
  description         = "AVD ${var.prefix} Workspace"
  depends_on          = [azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.hostpool, azurerm_virtual_desktop_application_group.desktop_application_group]
}
resource "time_rotating" "avd_token" {
  rotation_days = 30
}
# Create AVD host pool
resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool" "hostpool" {
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.location
  name                     = "${var.prefix}${var.hostpool_name}"
  friendly_name            = "${var.prefix} Host Pool"
  validate_environment     = true
  custom_rdp_properties    = "targetisaadjoined:i:1;drivestoredirect:s:*;audiomode:i:0;videoplaybackmode:i:1;redirectclipboard:i:1;redirectprinters:i:1;devicestoredirect:s:*;redirectcomports:i:1;redirectsmartcards:i:1;usbdevicestoredirect:s:*;enablecredsspsupport:i:1;redirectwebauthn:i:1;use multimon:i:1;enablerdsaadauth:i:1"
  description              = "${var.prefix} Terraform HostPool"
  type                     = "Pooled"
  maximum_sessions_allowed = 10
  load_balancer_type       = "BreadthFirst" #[BreadthFirst DepthFirst]
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd
  ]
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool_registration_info" "registrationinfo" {
  hostpool_id     = azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.hostpool.id
  expiration_date = time_rotating.avd_token.rotation_rfc3339
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.hostpool
  ]
}

# Create AVD DAG
resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_application_group" "desktop_application_group" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.name
  host_pool_id        = azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.hostpool.id
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.location
  type                = "Desktop"
  name                = "${var.prefix}-desktop-application-group"
  friendly_name       = "${var.prefix} Desktop AppGroup"
  description         = "AVD ${var.prefix} Application Group"
  depends_on          = [azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.hostpool, azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.network_file_share]

}

# Associate Workspace and DAG
resource "azurerm_virtual_desktop_workspace_application_group_association" "workspace-desktop_application_group" {
  application_group_id = azurerm_virtual_desktop_application_group.desktop_application_group.id
  workspace_id         = azurerm_virtual_desktop_workspace.workspace.id
}
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  name                = "avd_rdp_nsg"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.name

  security_rule {
    name                       = "allow_rdp_sg"
    priority                   = 900
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "3389"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
  security_rule {
    name                       = "allow_azure_file"
    priority                   = 901
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "445"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
  security_rule {
    name                       = "allow_https"
    priority                   = 300
    direction                  = "Outbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "443"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
  security_rule {
    name                       = "allow_http"
    priority                   = 301
    direction                  = "Outbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "80"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}
# Create Network Interface for virtual machines
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "avd_vm_nic" {
  count               = var.rdsh_count
  name                = "AVD-${var.prefix}-${count.index + 1}-nic"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.location

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "nic${count.index + 1}_config"
    subnet_id                     = var.subnet_id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd,
    azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool_registration_info.registrationinfo
  ]
}
resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "association" {
  count = var.rdsh_count
  depends_on = [ azurerm_network_security_group.nsg, azurerm_network_interface.avd_vm_nic ]
  network_interface_id      = azurerm_network_interface.avd_vm_nic.*.id[count.index]
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.id
}
# Create Virtual Machines for AVD
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "avd_session_host" {
  count                 = var.rdsh_count
  name                  = "AVD-${var.prefix}-${count.index + 1}"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.name
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd.location
  size                  = var.vm_size
  network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.avd_vm_nic.*.id[count.index]}"]
  provision_vm_agent    = true
  admin_username        = var.local_admin_username
  admin_password        = var.local_admin_password

  os_disk {
    name                 = "avd-${lower(var.prefix)}-${count.index + 1}"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop"
    offer     = "Windows-11"
    sku       = "win11-22h2-avd"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.rg-avd,
    azurerm_network_interface.avd_vm_nic
  ]
}

# Register VM with Azure Virtual Desktop
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vm_avd_associate" {
  depends_on = [
      azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.avd_session_host
  ]
  count = var.rdsh_count
  name                 = "Microsoft.PowerShell.DSC"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.avd_session_host.*.id[count.index]
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Powershell"
  type                 = "DSC"
  type_handler_version = "2.73"
  settings = <<-SETTINGS
    {
        "modulesUrl": "https://wvdportalstorageblob.blob.core.windows.net/galleryartifacts/Configuration_01-19-2023.zip",
        "ConfigurationFunction": "Configuration.ps1\\AddSessionHost",
        "Properties" : {
          "hostPoolName" : "${azurerm_virtual_desktop_host_pool.hostpool.name}",
          "aadJoin": true
        }
    }
SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
  {
    "properties": {
      "registrationInfoToken": "${local.registration_token}"
    }
  }
PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}
#Join VM to domain
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "AADLoginForWindows" {
  depends_on = [
      azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.avd_session_host,
      azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vm_avd_associate
  ]
  count = var.rdsh_count
  name                 = "AADLoginForWindows"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.avd_session_host.*.id[count.index]
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory"
  type                 = "AADLoginForWindows"
  type_handler_version = "1.0"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
}
/* resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "addaadjprivate" {
    depends_on = [
      azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.AADLoginForWindows
    ]
  count = var.rdsh_count
  name                 = "AADJPRIVATE"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.avd_session_host.*.id[count.index]
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.10"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -Command \"${local.powershell_command}\""
    }
SETTINGS
} */

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "network_file_share" {
    depends_on = [
      azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.AADLoginForWindows ]
  count = var.rdsh_count
  name                 = "enable-network-discovery"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.avd_session_host.*.id[count.index]
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.10"
  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
    "commandToExecute": "powershell -encodedCommand ${textencodebase64(file(var.network_fileshare_config), "UTF-16LE")}" 
    }
    SETTINGS
}
```

PowerShellScript:

```
# Set Network Discovery rule
Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Network Discovery" -Enabled True
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup 'Network Discovery' | Set-NetFirewallRule -Profile 'Public' -Enabled true
Enable-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "File and Printer Sharing"
Invoke-Expression -Command "net use `"\\avddevfileshare.file.core.windows.net\tm-prog`" /user:`"localhost\avddevfileshare`" `"password`" /persistent:`"yes`" /global"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "C:\tm_prog" | Out-Null
Copy-Item -Path "\\avddevfileshare.file.core.windows.net\tm-prog\*" -Destination "C:\tm_prog" -Recurse -Force
# Create Shortcut
$batchScriptContent = @"
@echo off
net use `"\\avddevfileshare.file.core.windows.net\tm-data`" /user:`"localhost\avddevfileshare`" `"password`" /persistent:`"yes`" /global
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > CreateShortcut.vbs
echo sLinkFile = "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Desktop\tangoMediaCG.lnk" >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo oLink.TargetPath = "C:\tm_prog\prog\win\tangoMediaCG.exe" >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo oLink.Save >> CreateShortcut.vbs
cscript CreateShortcut.vbs 
del CreateShortcut.vbs
"@
# Define the path for the batch script
$batchScriptPath = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\CreateShortcut.bat"
$batchScriptContent | Out-File -FilePath $batchScriptPath -Encoding ASCII
Start-Process -FilePath $batchScriptPath -Verb RunAs -PassThru
$gpPath = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"
# Set the script execution policy
Set-ItemProperty -Path $gpPath -Name "EnableScriptBlockLogging" -Value 1
Set-ItemProperty -Path $gpPath -Name "EnableScripts" -Value 1
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
# Register the script to run at startup
$taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "cmd.exe" -Argument "/c `"$batchScriptPath`""
$taskTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogon
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $taskAction -Trigger $taskTrigger -TaskName "CreateShortcutTask" -User "LocalAdmin" -Password "password" -Force -RunLevel Highest -Force
New-Item -Path HKLM:/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/RDInfraAgent/AADJPrivate; shutdown -r -t 10; exit 0
```

I tried to edit the PowerShell Script but looks like it does not work. I expect to have the persistent unassigned drive letter mounted UNC Path of the Azure File Share globally that anyone can access it without prompting the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

> Mounting Azure File Storage to Azure Virtual Desktop Session Host using Terraform and PowerShell Script.

To mount `Azure File Storage` to `Azure Virtual Desktop`, you can use the following Terraform code to mount the `Azure File share`

I created a **.ps1** file named 'fileshare.ps1' in the same directory to run the `PowerShell script` in the Terraform code, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Here is the updated Terraform code.

```json
    resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "avd_vm" {
      name                  = "demo-avd"
      resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      location              = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      size                  = "Standard_DS2_v2"
     network_interface_ids  =  [azurerm_network_interface.nic.id]
      provision_vm_agent    = true
      admin_username        = "Venkat"
      admin_password        = "Welcome@123$"
    
      os_disk {
        name                 = "avd-os"
        caching              = "ReadWrite"
        storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
      }
    
      source_image_reference {
        publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop"
        offer     = "Windows-10"
        sku       = "20h2-evd"
        version   = "latest"
      }
    }
    resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "example" {
      name                 = "sample-hostname"
      virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.avd_vm.id
      publisher            = "Microsoft.Powershell"
      type                 = "DSC"
      type_handler_version = "2.73"
    
    settings = <<SETTINGS
        {   
        "commandToExecute": "powershell fileshare.ps1"
        }
    SETTINGS
    
      tags = {
        environment = "Production"
      }
    }
```

**Terraform apply**

After running the above terraform code, `Extension` has been provisioned successfully.

[image]

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/configure-azure-virtual-desktop

Comment: I know about this script. However, in my situation, I want to mount the Azure File Share without drive letter but I still cannot do it.

Comment: My purpose is to mount a Azure File Share to session hosts in Azure Virtual Desktop. The mounting point is without drive letter, persistent and global for all users can access the UNC path. Could you please fix my Powershell script on the post? I also need to perform other task in the script as well. I am so hopeless to find out the solution. @Venkat V

Comment: For mounting Azure File share without drive letter, it's not possible.

Comment: You can try this code 
$storageAccountName = ""
$storageAccountKey = ""
$fileShareName = ""
$uncPath = "\\${storageAccountName}.file.core.windows.net\${fileShareName}"
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("", ("" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force))

New-PSDrive -Name $fileShareName -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $uncPath -Persist -Credential $credential -Scope Global

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried to run „net use \\storageaccountlink …“ inside the session host with „Run As Admin“ using cmd prompt or powershell, the Azure File Share is mapped without drive letter successfully. However, with the powershell script written above, I tried two ways: Create a task scheduler to mount the Azure File Share whenever user logins but I got error „Access is denied“ from batch script. The second is that I want to run the command „Start-Process“ and the „Create Shortcut“ part in the batch script works well; but the mounting without drive letter does not work.

Comment: Please help me, I just added new comment @Venkat V

Comment: In your PowerShell script, you are using the net use command to mount the Azure File Share. However, this command requires the credentials to be provided every time the script is run. To avoid this, you can use the New-SmbMapping cmdlet to create a persistent SMB mapping to the Azure File Share.